# how to create history tables or audit tables on ALL_IND_COLUMNS?

Tags: sql, oracle, version-control, plsql

I am writing a utility which keeps track of dropped indices or missing indices. I got to know about 2 index tables namely `ALL_IND_COLUMNS` and `ALL_INDEXES` which contains all the indices associated to each table in the database. I'm using `ALL_IND_COLUMNS` because it even contains column names.

Now i want to create a history table which keeps track of all the changes to `ALL_IND_COLUMNS`. I had thought of writing a `trigger` so that when there is an `insert` , `delete` or `update` on `ALL_IND_COLUMNS` the data all be inserted to history table but I heard there will be performance issue if we create a triggers on data dictionary tables. So, I want to know if there is any better alternative to solve this problem in SQL or PL/SQL. Im using using oracle 11g.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indexes are NOT meant to be created and dropped frequently. Even if you make so frequent changes, then you should be able to track the changes using `source code version control`

Comment: Yeah but I have to take all possibilities. Can you please elaborate. I don't know what `source code version control` is? :(

Comment: You can try [DDL trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6061) reacting only on `ora_dict_obj_type = 'INDEX'` and store all needed informations from `ALL_IND_COLUMNS` in your audit table before DDL happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Indexes** are **NOT** meant to be **created** and **dropped** frequently. Even if you make so frequent changes, then you should be able to track the changes using `source code version control`.

There are many tools available for **VERSION CONTROL**. You should install and create required tags and branches for your database objects. Any modification to the database objects should go through database version control.

For example, the scripts that you use to `create/drop the indexes`, should be in the version control under **INDEXES**.

- Checkout the code/scripts from repository to you local directory
- Make necessary modifications
- Test it locally
- Check in your changes with required description

I personally use **Subversion** for my `database version control`.

For more details, read this link [Using Source Code Control in Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/srccode-otn-088877.html)

Read this wiki link about [Revision control, also known as version control and source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

Comment: is there any way we can do it using `PL/SQL` because I'll be using this query in perl script later on.